# Make Google index pages differently depending on which container is shown or hidden using AlpineJS

Tags: javascript, dom, seo, alpine.js

I'm currently using AlpineJS on a website to show a Lightbox, so whenever a user clicks on an image I hide the current content container and instead show a Lightbox container with the fullscreen image and some metadata on it. AlpineJS will also rewrite the url, so when a user shares a link to a fullscreen image it will show the Lightbox directly and not the current content page.

This is working pretty well so far, but I'd like to be able that search engines like Google would recognise the linkable Lightbox page as its own page and index it as well.

So for example:

`https://example.org/photoraphers/some_photographer/works` -> this is showing a grid view of all of a photographers images.

`https://example.org/photoraphers/some_photographer/works?show=work&work_id=some_photograph_id` -> this is showing a selected photograph in fullscreen in the Lightbox

As both urls are currently the same HTML page with the only difference of AlpineJS showing/hiding certain containers, Google doesn't recognise them as different pages. Is there a way to tell the Google bot that links to the Lightbox images should be handled as their own pages? And could I use AlpineJS to update the page metadata fields and the title?

Here is the relevant parts of the code (using Statamic as CMS):

```html
<!-- We show a list of the photographer's works by default here -->
<div x-show="!showLightbox" class="grid-cols-4 gap-1.5">
    {{ selection_of_works }}
    {{ unless no_results }}
    <div x-transition id="lightbox" data-lightbox-index="{{ index }}" data-lightbox-id="{{ id }}">
        <a x-on:click='show("{{ id }}")' href="javascript:void(0)"
           data-src="{{ glide :src='image:0' preset='full' }}"
           data-title="{{ title | sanitize }}" data-year="{{ year | sanitize }}">
            <picture class="object-contain">
                <img src="{{ glide :src='image:0' preset='320w' }}" alt="{{title}}">
            </picture>
        </a>
        <div class="mt-1 mb-4">
            <h1><span class="italic">{{ title }}</span>{{ if (year) }}, {{ year }}{{ /if }}</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    {{ /unless }}
    {{ /selection_of_works }}
</div>

<!-- Unless the Lightbox is toggled, then we show this container instead -->
<div x-show="showLightbox" class="absolute inset-0 h-full w-full z-10 bg-white">
    <div class="w-full h-full flex flex-row items-center gap-1.5 p-3">
        <div class="hidden md:block flex-shrink-0 cursor-pointer pt-6 pb-6 pr-6">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" x-on:click="prev">prev</a>
        </div>

        <div x-swipe:left="next" x-swipe:right="prev" class="w-full h-full flex flex-col flex-1">
            <div class="w-full h-full overflow-auto pb-6 pt-7 md:p-16 xl:p-32">
                <img class="w-full h-full object-contain" x-bind:alt="image.captionTitle" x-bind:src="image.imageSrc" x-bind:srcset="image.imageSrcset">
            </div>
            <div class="text-center flex flex-col justify-center items-center flex-shrink-0">
                <span x-html="image.caption"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the most relevant AlpineJS code:

```js
Alpine.data('lightbox', () => ({
images: [],
showLightbox: false,
image: {
    index: "",
    id: "",
    imageSrc: "",
    imageSrcset: "",
    caption: "",
},
init() {
    // load images retrieves all of the photographers works by using document.querySelectorAll("#lightbox") and parsing through it
    this.images = loadImages()
    this.showLightbox = new URLSearchParams(location.search).get('show') === 'work'

    let workId = "";
    if (new URLSearchParams(location.search).has('work_id')) {
        workId = new URLSearchParams(location.search).get('work_id')
    }

    this.show(workId)
},
show(workId) {
    let image = this.images.find(element => element.id === workId)

    if (!image) {
        this.close()
        return
    }

    this.image = image;
    this.showLightbox = true;

    updateLightboxUrl(this.showLightbox, this.image)
}
}))
```

Comment: Google can index query strings. Have you tried adding the pages with query string to the Sitemap?